# Is there any way to rename a Cargo project?

Tags: linux, rust, rust-cargo

I created a project using: `cargo new projectname --bin`.
How do I change `projectname` to some other name?

I checked the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/yakkety/man1/cargo.1.html#contenttoc2) and the [Cargo documentation](http://doc.crates.io/guide.html). I also ran:

- `cargo help`
- `cargo --list`
- `man cargo`

In the metadata files (Cargo.toml, Cargo.lock, ...), there is "name" and "path". I suppose I could change them manually, but I don't know if that would break anything.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think that you should change it manually. Not so difficult, really.

I run this code:

```
$ cargo new smurf --bin
     Created binary (application) `smurf` project
$ cd smurf/
smurf$ cargo build
     ....
smurf$ grep -rl smurf .
./target/debug/smurf.d
./target/debug/smurf
./target/debug/.fingerprint/smurf-35f069edf7faaa12/bin-smurf-35f069edf7faaa12.json
./target/debug/.fingerprint/smurf-35f069edf7faaa12/dep-bin-smurf-35f069edf7faaa12
./target/debug/deps/smurf-35f069edf7faaa12
./Cargo.lock
./Cargo.toml
```

From all these files, the whole `target` may be just deleted. The `.lock` file can also be deleted. And the `Cargo.toml`... well you can just edit it.

I tried changing only the `Cargo.toml` and all just works. However you end up with useless files in `target` so I recommend deleting those anyway.

Comment: Sweet! It seems pretty painless, I guess this will have to do until the Cargo team implement it natively.

Comment: cargo clean will remove the entire target directory. See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-clean.html

Answer (score 5):

Under Linux this is fairly strait forward:

- go to the directory where your project is located e.g. if your project was called hello_world in a folder named rust then go to the rust folder
  `pi@raspberrypi:~/workspace/rust/hello_world $ cd ..`
- from there you can rename the project by

  1. mv [current name of the project] [name you want] to move. E.g. if I wanted to rename it from hello_world to hello_rust I would type
     `mv hello_world/ hello_rust/` to rename the folder.
  2. now you only have to change the name in your Cargo.toml file:

     - `pi@raspberrypi:~/workspace/rust $ cd hello_rust/`
     - `pi@raspberrypi:~/workspace/rust/hello_rust $ geany Cargo.toml`
     - (I am using geany but you can use whatever text editor you like)
     - in Cargo.toml in the second line change
     - `name = "hello_world"` to `name = "hello_rust"`

Hope that this might help someone in the future

Comment: TL;DR - Just make a copy of the original package, open the copied directory in your IDE, and change `name` in the Cargo.toml file, but just make sure the new name matches the new directory's name.